# PSR-12 and assigning same value to multiple variables

Tags: php, psr-12

Is it allowed to assign multiple variables on the same line in PSR-12?

For example:

```php
$count = $score = 0;
```

Comment: As a personal opinion, it can actually make it easy to miss that the subsequent variables are declared.  There is no reason you can't use it and it comes down to style.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. If it's not explicitly stated, then there is no standard. Either works.

Also, chain assignment like that just makes the code cleaner so I personally would not see a reason to why it should not be allowed.

https://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-12/